# ¿Cómo obtener con una cosnulta sql un ID no registrado dentro de un intervalo dado?

Tags: sql, oracle-12c

Me explico,

Necesito crear una consulta sql para obtener un identificador numérico no registrado en una tabla que se encuentre dentro de un intervalo.

| ID | CODIGO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30000 |
| 2 | 30001 |
| 3 | 30003 |

Por ejemplo, si tengo los datos de la tabla de arriba llamada "CODIGOS" tendría que hacer una consulta para obtener el menor código que no este en uso en el rango entre 30000 y 30100.

Es decir, la consulta me debería dar como resultado el 30002.

He probado con LVL y lo único que he conseguido es obtener el siguiente código libre dentro de ese rango (el 30004), per no consigo averiguar cómo hacer la query para averiguar si hay uno libre entre medias .

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(TO_NUMBER(CODIGO)), 30000) + 1 AS CODIGO
FROM CODIGOS 
WHERE CODIGO >= 30000 AND CODIGO <= 30100
```

Voy bien encaminado utilizando NVL? Alguien me puede ayudar a hacer esta query? No he encontrado soluciones a este problema en todo el foro :(

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2):

[Desde Oracle 12g](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/pattern-matching-in-oracle-database-12cr1) puedes hacer uso de [`MATCH_RECOGNIZE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e12048/pattern_recog.htm#CQLLR1531).

Para este caso sería algo así:

```
SELECT 
  RESULT AS MINFREE 
FROM CODIGOS
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY CODIGO
  MEASURES LAST(b.CODIGO) + 1 AS RESULT
  PATTERN ( ^ a b* c )
  DEFINE b AS CODIGO = PREV(CODIGO) + 1,
         c AS CODIGO > PREV(CODIGO) + 1
)
;
```

Aquí un fiddle de prueba:

```
CREATE TABLE CODIGOS(
    CODIGO NUMBER NOT NULL
);
```

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO CODIGOS  VALUES (3000)
    INTO CODIGOS  VALUES (3001)
    INTO CODIGOS  VALUES (3003)

SELECT 1 FROM dual;
```

```
3 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * FROM CODIGOS;
```

| CODIGO |
| --- |
| 3000 |
| 3001 |
| 3003 |

```
SELECT 
  RESULT AS MINFREE 
FROM CODIGOS
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY CODIGO
  MEASURES LAST(b.CODIGO) + 1 AS RESULT
  PATTERN ( ^ a b* c )
  DEFINE b AS CODIGO = PREV(CODIGO) + 1,
         c AS CODIGO > PREV(CODIGO) + 1
)
;
```

| MINFREE |
| --- |
| 3002 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/opN3aa2w)